# Can I split a method across two cs files?

Tags: c#

I have .cs that is over 33K lines long. Whenever this file is open Visual Studio slows down tremendously and occasionally momentarily freezes. All this class is  is a dictionary initialization.

Is there some way to split my Initialize() method across multiple .cs?

Comment: Have you considered moving the data for initialization to some sort of persistent store (like a database or a flat file) and then loading the dictionary from that?

Comment: You could also look at [Partial Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx), but that would be a last resort (IMO).

Comment: @Tim that's not what partial methods are for. You can put the signature in one file and the implementation in another, but you can't split it across files.

Comment: You could split it into multiple methods, and use partial classes to move them to different files. Partial Methods won't help, you can't split a method, just declare it elsewhere. But really, move the data out of the code.

Comment: 33K lines to initialize a dictionary???

Comment: @dman2306 - Ah, that's what I get for not reading the fine print.  :)

Comment: This better be the Oxford dictionary.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use anything from Microsoft other than the OS :P Literally *everything* (*including* the OS) lags so hard on any laptop without a SSD

Answer (score 5):

If your class simply acts as storage for a bunch of different dictionary items, you may want to consider storing those items in a file instead. You could store that file in the assembly as a .txt or .xml file. That way, you could edit the file and have your program load the data at runtime.

Simply create a new file in your solution and set it to "Embedded Resource", then load the data into your class instead.

For more information on embedded resources, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to break your method into smaller chunks.  Our team tends to keep methods around one screen in length, which is about 50-60 lines max.  You can call other methods that will in turn call other methods, but it sounds like you have way too much happening in a sinlge method.

You *can* split a class across multiple files by using the `partial` keyword:

```
// file Test1.cs
public partial class Test{} //...

// file Test2.cs
public partial class Test{} //...
```

As long as they are in the same namespace, an instance of the class would have all the methods declared in both files.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: While I agree in principal (60 lines even sounds like a lot to me), given his use case of just a dictionary initializer, from the perspective of "lines of code per method" I'd argue his method is 1 line... just a ridiculously long line, since it can be reduced to a single logical operation "Add 33,000 items to my Dictionary." From the sounds of it, it sounds like it's just `dict.Add()` over and over.

Comment: @dman2306, true, I didn't read that part.  There still must be some logical break.  If it's animals, e.g., you could have methods for `animals.AddRange(GetPigs());`, `animals.AddRange(GetSheep());`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No. When it comes to partial classes, this works because order is irrelevant. The files are simply "merged." The order of the methods and the properties, etc. does not matter. When it comes to splitting a method, how could you do that? Should the part in File1 run first or the part in File2? The execution order matters. The compiler wouldn't know what to do.

What you could do instead is break it up into multiple smaller methods, then spread the methods across class files as a `partial class`. For example, if the dictionary were of names, you could have File1 contain a method `LoadNamesAThroughL` and File2 contain a method `LoadNamesMThroughZ` or something like that. Then your `Initialize` could call both of those in the order you desire.

Comment: Yep, but what if I want to split Initialize? :) Fact of the matter is that I'm looking for splitting my class constructor into multiple files (to keep relevant parts together) and there's apparently no way of doing it. As far as order of execution is concerned, this could simply be solved using an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Partial Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) to do this. Break up your Initialize function into smaller functions, put the individual functions in different files, and then have Initialize call them in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [partial class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to split it across files.

You would also need to break the method into multiple methods (which a 33k line method is already begging for).

Example from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Use Partial Class

public partial class Employee
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
        }
    }

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

Works with properties also